# Confused about language and words in logic

Tags: logic, formal-languages

I am very confused about how to interpret the following.

If we write $\{0,1\}^{+}$=$\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{0,1\}^{n}$

then I am told that elements  of $\{0,1\}^{+}$ are called words and subsists of it are called languages,

Then I was asked,

if we consider $$g: P( \{0,1\}^{+}) \to P( \{0,1\}^{+})$$ defined as

$g(X)=X \cup \{w01:w \in X\} \cup \{\tau\}$

where $\tau$ represents the word of zero length, then find the least fixed point of g ordered by inclusion.

I have been trying to make sense of it but cant make progress. I know that a fixed point is an element $X$ such that $g(X)=X$

I know that since we want the least, the fixed point has to be less then any other fixed points ordered by inclusion to.

Can anyone help to make sense of this? Thank you

Comment: What this says is you need an $X$ such that $\tau \in X$ and $w\in X \rightarrow w01 \in X$.  What members must every such $X$ necessarily have?  Hint: induction

Comment: Thank you for response. Yes I understand that X will have to contain \tau since it will be added on regardless, and I understand that if w is in X then we would need w01 in X.  What members must every such X have? I think I could better answer if I had a better understanding of what w01 means. I am still a bit confused on that

Comment: $w01$ is the concatenation of $w$ with $01$. In other words, it is the word you get when you tack "$01$" on to the end of $w$.

Comment: @PersonaA $w01$ is the string gotten by adjoining $01$ to $w$. For instance, if $w=011$, then $w01=01101$. Does that make sense?

Comment: so is saying $\tau$ is in X essentially saying that the string 0 is in X? and so since 0 is in X then would need 001 in X? and then would need 00101 in X, 0010101 , etc? Or am I making misunderstandings here

Comment: $\tau$ is not "$0$", $\tau$ is " ".  It's the string with no symbols in it.

Comment: oh I understand that, it is the empty string basically

Comment: @PersonaA exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the function $g$ as a way to *expand a language*: you feed it a language $L$, and it spits out a bigger language $L'$ (bigger in the sense that $L\subseteq L'$).

For example, consider the function $h$ given by $h(L)=\{\sigma: \sigma\in L\mbox{ or }\sigma=001011101\}.$ This takes a language, and enlarges it by adding the string $001011101$. The least fixed point of $h$ is the language $M=\{001011101\}$; clearly $h(M)=M$ (all $h$ does is add something already in $M$), so $M$ is *a* fixed point of $h$.

Now, I claim that $M$ is in fact the *least* fixed point of $h$. Why? Well, suppose $X$ is a fixed point of $h$ - that is, $h(X)=X$. Then $001011101\in X$, since $001011101\in h(X)$ by definition of $h$ and $h(X)=X$. But this means $M\subseteq X$.

---

Here's another one: $j(L)=L\cup\{\sigma^\smallfrown\tau: \sigma,\tau\in L\}$. This $j$ takes in a language, and spits out the language consisting of everything that's either already in $L$, or can be gotten by putting two things in $L$ together. For instance, if $L=\{0\}$, then $j(L)=\{0, 00\}$ and $j(j(L))=\{0, 00, 000, 0000\}$.

The least fixed point of $j$ is the empty language, $\emptyset$. Why? Well clearly $\emptyset\subseteq X$ for any fixed point $X$ of $j$ (since $\emptyset$ is a subset of everything); and $\emptyset$ is a fixed point of $j$.

---

Note that each of the examples above can be gotten by starting with the empty language, and applying the "enlarger" in question. In both these cases, we only needed to apply the enlarger *once*. This isn't true in general: consider the map $k(L)=L\cup\{0\}\cup\{\sigma\smallfrown\tau: \sigma,\tau\in L\}$. Then:

- $k(\emptyset)=\{0\}$.
- $k(\{0\})=\{0, 00\}$.
- $k(\{0, 00\})=\{0, 00, 000, 0000\}$.

It doesn't look like we're going to get a fixed point this way . . .

. . . but we can take the "limit" of these stages! Let $M_0=\emptyset$, $M_{n+1}=k(M_n)$, and $$M=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} k(M_n).$$ Can you figure out what $M$ is? (HINT: see if you can figure out what $M_n$ is for each $n$, first . . .) Can you see why $M$ is the least fixed point of $k$?

---

Hopefully this makes it more clear what the problem is asking. Try to find the least fixed point of your example function analogously to $k$, above!

Comment: Thanks.  First example I get completely thanks for clarifying the definitions for me with that one. For the second one, I am a bit confused on notation, for example if $j(L)=\{0,00\}$ then which two elements are you combining to get 0 and 00 in j(j(L)?

Comment: @PersonaA I'm not - note that $j(X)$ *includes* the original $X$! $j(X)=X\cup$[stuff].

Comment: Oh that makes sense, so I am following along with the k(L) example and how you are getting its entries. So would the M being $\{0,00,000,0000,00000,.....\}$?

Comment: @PersonaA yes, that's exactly what it is.

Comment: So in my case if $M0= \emptyset $ then $M1=\{\tau,01\}$ and then would $M2=\{\tau,01,0101\} $or am I missing some combination for my M2?

Comment: @PersonaA Yup, that's correct. Can you guess what the least fixed point should be?

Comment: I would say $M=\{\tau,01,0101,010101,01010101,...\}$?

Comment: @PersonaA Yup. Now, all you have to do is prove it. :P (HINT: showing it's a fixed point is easy, so just let $\sigma_n$ be $n$ copies of $01$ (so $\sigma_0=\tau$ and $\sigma_2=0101$, etc.), and show that if $X$ is any fixed point then $\sigma_n\in X$ for every $n$. This, in turn, is via induction.)

Comment: Thank you very much. In the argument don't we show that any fixed point must contain these elements at a minimum?

Comment: @PersonaA Yup, and since $M$ contains *exactly* those elements, $M$ is a subset of any fixed point. Since $M$ is itself a fixed point, that means $M$ is in fact the least fixed point.